How to print ticket with image automatically in java?
I need to print a sales ticket with a barcode to be scanned later.
The problem is that the way our ticket is printed is stored in a String by consulting the data from the DB, and then transformed into bytes so that it is automatically printed on a Bixolon SRP 330II mini printer.
This is the code that I have:
private void imprimirT(String tk, int tipo, String folioFactura, boolean facturaOnline) throws SQLException, IOException {
        System.out.println("\n\nInicia metodo imprimirT(" + tk + ", " + folioFactura + ", " + facturaOnline + ")");
        System.out.println("Ticket:" + tk);
        this.con.conectarlv();
        String fec = "00-00-0000", hor = "00:00:00", suc = "", emp = "", let = "";
        Double sub = 0.00, iva = 0.00, iep = 0.00, tot = 0.00, efe = 0.00, doc = 0.00, dol = 0.00, des = 0.00, cam = 0.00;

        String Ticket = "";
        PreparedStatement ti = this.con.conlv.prepareStatement("SELECT ven_fec, ven_hora, suc_des, ven_emp, ven_sub, ven_iva, ven_iep, ven_tot, ven_efe, ven_fpa, ven_dol, ven_cambio, ven_let FROM ventas, sucursales WHERE ven_id='" + tk + "' AND ven_suc=suc_nom GROUP BY ven_id");
        ResultSet t = ti.executeQuery();
        while (t.next()) {
            System.out.println("Entro al ticket, emp:" + t.getString(4));
            fec = t.getString(1);
            hor = t.getString(2);
            suc = t.getString(3);
            emp = t.getString(4);
            sub = t.getDouble(5);
            iva = t.getDouble(6);
            iep = t.getDouble(7);
            tot = t.getDouble(8);
            efe = t.getDouble(9);
            doc = t.getDouble(10);
            dol = t.getDouble(11);
            cam = t.getDouble(12);
            let = t.getString(13);
        }
        des = 0.0;
        if (tipo == 1) {
            Ticket = Ticket + "\r\n DEVOLUCION";
        }
        Ticket = Ticket + "\r\nFecha: " + fec + " Hora: " + hor + "\r\n" + this.cEncabezado;
        if (this.cfol.equals("1")) {
            Ticket = Ticket + "\r\nFolio: " + tk;
        }
        Ticket = Ticket + "\r\nSucursal: " + suc;
        Ticket = Ticket + "\r\nAtendido por:" + emp + "\r\n";
        Ticket = Ticket + "\r\nPRODUCTO        CANT      P.U.     TOTAL";

        ti = this.con.conlv.prepareStatement("SELECT nve_prod, vde_can, vde_pre, vde_sub FROM ventas_desc, prod_des WHERE vde_fol='" + tk + "' AND vde_pro=nom_prod");
        t = ti.executeQuery();
        while (t.next()) {
            Ticket = Ticket + "\r\n" + String.format("%1$-15s", t.getString(1)) + "\r\n" + String.format("%1$20s", t.getString(2)) + String.format("%1$10s", df.format(t.getDouble(3))) + String.format("%1$10s", df.format(t.getDouble(4)));
        }
        Ticket = Ticket + "\r\n";
        Ticket = Ticket + "\r\nSUB-TOTAL                       $" + String.format("%1$7s", df.format(sub));
        Ticket = Ticket + "\r\nI.V.A.                          $" + String.format("%1$7s", df.format(iva));
        Ticket = Ticket + "\r\nI.E.P.S.                        $" + String.format("%1$7s", df.format(iep));
        Ticket = Ticket + "\r\nTOTAL                           $" + String.format("%1$7s", df.format(tot));
        Ticket = Ticket + "\r\n";
        if (efe > 0) {
            Ticket = Ticket + "\r\nEFECTIVO                        $" + String.format("%1$7s", df.format(efe));
        }
        if (doc > 0) {
            Ticket = Ticket + "\r\nDOCUMENTO                       $" + String.format("%1$7s", df.format(doc));
        }
        if (dol > 0) {
            Ticket = Ticket + "\r\nDOLLAR                          $" + String.format("%1$7s", df.format(dol));
        }
        if (des > 0) {
            Ticket = Ticket + "\r\nDESCUENTO                       $" + String.format("%1$7s", df.format(des));
        }
        Ticket = Ticket + "\r\nSU CAMBIO                       $" + String.format("%1$7s", df.format(cam));
        Ticket = Ticket + "\r\n";
        Ticket = Ticket + "\r\n" + let;
        Ticket = Ticket + "\n";

        if (facturaOnline) {
            Ticket = Ticket + "\r\nFOLIO DE FACTURACION: " + folioFactura;
            Ticket = Ticket + "\nPAGINA WEB: www.farmaciasmedisim.com";
            //Ticket = Ticket+"\n";
        }

        if (tipo == 0) {
            Ticket = Ticket + "\r\n" + this.cPie;
        }
        Ticket = Ticket + "\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n";
        //Print Structure of ticket
        byte[] bytes;
        bytes = Ticket.getBytes();
        System.out.println("Sesion:" + this.sesion + "Impresora: " + this.per.sesionImpresora(this.sesion) + " Imprimir Ticket");
        String printerName = this.per.sesionImpresora(this.sesion);
        DocFlavor docFormat = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;

        Doc docp = new SimpleDoc(finalPrintBytes, docFormat, null);
        //Include printer name a his attributes
        AttributeSet attributeSet = new HashAttributeSet();

        attributeSet.add(new PrinterName(printerName, null));
        attributeSet = new HashAttributeSet();
        //Support of color or not
        attributeSet.add(ColorSupported.NOT_SUPPORTED);
        PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(docFormat, attributeSet);
        int Pval = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < services.length; i++) {
            String PintList = services[i].getName();
            if (PintList.equals(printerName)) {
                Pval = i;
                break;
            } else {
                Pval = 100000000;
            }
        }
        if (Pval != 100000000) {
            try {
                DocPrintJob pj = services[Pval].createPrintJob();
                pj.print(docp, new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet());
            } catch (PrintException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error de Impresion");
                System.out.println(ex.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error de Impresion");
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            } finally {

            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "NO SE ENCONTRO LA IMPRESORA", "ERROR", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }

        this.con.cerrarlv();
        CortarT();
        System.out.println("Fin metodo imprimirT(" + tk + ", " + folioFactura + ", " + facturaOnline + ")\n\n");
    }

The ticket is printed as shown in this image.
I've looked into how to create a barcode, but I've only found that the barcode is created as an image and saved in PDF.
In others I've seen that they save it in PDF first and then choose the printer to save it, which I don't want, since I want the barcode to be printed on the same ticket.
This is the code with which I create and save the barcode in PDF:
private void generarCodigoBarras() {
        System.out.println("\n\nInicia Funcion generarCodigoBarras()");
        String code = "";
        try {
            Document doc = new Document();
            PdfWriter pdf = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("codigoBarras.pdf"));
            doc.open();

            Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128();
            code = randomCode();
            code128.setCode(code);
            Image img128 = code128.createImageWithBarcode(pdf.getDirectContent(), BaseColor.BLACK, BaseColor.BLACK);
            doc.add(img128);
            //img128.scalePercent(100);
            //doc.add(new Paragraph(" "));
            doc.close();
            System.out.println("Fin Funcion generarCodigoBarras()\n\n");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | DocumentException e) {
            System.out.println("Error al generar codigo");
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            System.out.println("Fin Funcion generarCodigoBarras()\n\n");
        }
    }

    private String randomCode() {
        System.out.println("\n\nInicia Funcion randomCode()");
        Random randomNum = new Random();
        int max = 9999999, min = 1000000;
        String code = "";

        code = String.valueOf(randomNum.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min);
        System.out.println("El codigo es: " + code);
        System.out.println("Fin Funcion randomCode()\n\n");
        return code;
    }

To generate the barcode I use the itextpdf-5.5.8 library.
So I want to print the barcode at the end of the Ticket.
and I don't know how to save the barcode in an image without having to make it a pdf.
although I'm not sure that can be done in netbeans 8.0.2.
it's not necessary that it be with the same logic that I have, if you know of more ways to print a barcode on a miniprinter I would be very grateful if you could give me feedback with your knowledge.

Your Question would be better if you basically reversed the order of your content. Say up front immediately what is your specific technical issue. Your title should summarize that as well. Then mention your use of iText to create barcode. And so on. As currently written, few people will work their way through to figure out what you are really asking. The last thing to cover is your limited English, and that could be dropped really as the English is fine; it is your composition that needs improving.

By the way, there is a Spanish edition of Stack Overflow: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

I would use a PrintWriter to make a temporary file, rather than doing all that string appending. It will make your code cleaner and more efficient and will give you a record for the occasions where printing fails

To generate the barcode , you can find net.sf.barcode4j:barcode4j:2.1 , it can generate code 128  png image.
